# The type Task exists in both System.Threading and System.Threading.Tasks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp

I'm trying to help out a user of my Unity plugin who has encountered an odd error (see the issue [here](https://github.com/Placeholder-Software/Dissonance/issues/43)). When they build their project (with my plugin source code included) they get the following error:

> error CS0433: The type 'Task' exists in both 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Threading, Version=1.0.2856.102, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

I have a few questions related to this:

1. As far as I know `System.Threading` should not include a `Task` type on any framework (.Net, Mono or CoreCLR). Am I incorrect?
2. I told them to fully quality all type names in the file but they still get this error! How is it possible for the compiler to be confused about a `System.Threading` `Task` type if all of references in the file are `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`?
3. What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: `System.Threading.Tasks` and `System.Threading` as assemblies, not namespaces. Both contain a type `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`.

Comment: I'm not a Unity senior in any way, but look in the Build settings for the compiler version and look at the DLL files in the project. Also, is the user using Unity 2017 with the .NET 4 experimental support? Unity 5 does not support Tasks in any way

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto they're using Unity 5.5 but they're building for UWP which uses a different runtime (which does have task support).

Comment: @CodeCaster Aha that makes more sense. What System.Threading assembly ever had a task type in it?

Comment: A quick Google search tells something about the TPL on .NET 3.5.

Comment: You mean this TPL backport to NET3.5: [https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary) ? That's something I've heard of people using in Unity so it could well be that.

Comment: Tell the user to look at the project files, they might have imported System.Threading before

Comment: Oops, fixed the broken link in the question. I've asked the user to check for imported threading DLLs https://github.com/Placeholder-Software/Dissonance/issues/43#issuecomment-319078079

Comment: @Martin So it looks like this is an issue in another plugin asset, am I right?

Comment: Yep, some other asset is importing the TPL (backported to dotnet3.5). On Unity this is normally fine because it's a 3.5 runtime *except* when targeting windows store, then it's the 4.5 runtime (iirc). Since my plugin is distributed as source the compiler then gets confused when it comes to find the Task type and it finds *two*.

Comment: I've suggested that the user compile my plugin into a DLL in a separate project and then imports the DLL into the project. That will at least sidestep the problem.